# Page that uses the AMP Project and Razor Pages loads 8 times

Tags: c#, amp-html, razor-pages

In this minimal AMP HTML page (See http://ampproject.com) using Razor Pages, a breakpoint in OnGet is hit many times -- usually 8 times -- each time the page is loaded. Why should that be? Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Here is the c#.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
namespace iVoterGuide.com.Pages {
    public class IndexModel : PageModel {
        public void OnGet() {
            // ***** The breakpoint is set here
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the cshtml.  As you can see, it contains only the minimum scripts and other things required by AMP, plus the content "TEST BODY."

```
@page
@model iVoterGuide.com.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="IndexWholePage.cshtml">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>IndexWholePage</title>
    <!-- Structured Data
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <!-- JSON-LD -->
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "page title",
        "datePublished": "2018-05-19 14:52",
        "image": [
        "logo.jpg"
        ]
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="page url" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="page title" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="document image" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="document description" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="iVoterGuide" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:fb:app_id" content="" />
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@@iVoterGuide" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content=" " />
    <!-- Boilerplate Scripts/Styles
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
            <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
    <noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <!-- Fonts & Icons
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST BODY</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the ⚡ from , then everything works fine.

EDIT: Simplified and updated the question.

Comment: Multiple calls are being made for pre-rendering [How AMP Works](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how/)

Comment: Thank you! Isn't that horribly inefficient?  What if there are database calls?

Comment: AMP is a client side technology with a single responsibility. database calls would be outside of that. In your particular example I would say the mixing of the AMP and razor technologies may conflict.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but loading the same page so many times seems like a problem regardless of the server-size technology that is used. Could it be that this is only intended to be done the first time the page is loaded, and I'm inadvertently triggering something that causes it to be done every time? I used several articles about using AMP with the Razor engine, and I'm trying to follow their advice.